# How to trigger a build dependent on 2 upstream jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I am wondering if there is a way to trigger a job that is dependent on 2 (or more) UPSTREAM jobs in Jenkins?   Right now, if I add 2 jobs as upstream trigger, it seems to be an "OR condition".  I want it to evaluate like an "AND condition" .  Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Build Flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) should let you do this.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll be trying it today.  I appears to be what I need although its not completely clear how the syntax of the rules works.  I will have to fiddle with it.